# Altair - how to use datum to format a tooltip

Tags: python, charts, data-science, altair, vega

I am trying to format a tooltip using datum but, so far, without any success.
The tooltip I need is the something like "INV: 174,000.00". How can I do it?

## This is where I supposed to use datum:

```
text = line.mark_text(align='right', dx=-10, dy=-10).encode(
        text=alt.condition(nearest, f'Revenue:Q', alt.value(' '))
    ).transform_calculate(label='"INV: " + datum.Revenue')
```

## Full code:

```
import altair as alt
from altair import datum
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os



def areaChart():


    df = {
        'Stat': ['INV'],
        'Revenue': [474147.84, 2170326.05, 2184077.88, 3957965.97]
    }

    source = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(df, 0),
                        columns='Revenue', index=pd.RangeIndex(len(df['Stat']), name='Revenue'))
    print(source)
    source = source.reset_index().melt('Revenue', var_name='Analyzing', value_name='Revenue')

    nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                            fields=['Revenue'], empty='none')

    line = alt.Chart(source).mark_area(opacity=0.60).encode(
        x=alt.X(f'Stat:Q', axis=alt.AxisConfig()),
        y=f'Revenue:Q',
        color='Analyzing:N'
    )

    selectors = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
        x=f'Stat:Q',
        opacity=alt.value(0),
    ).add_selection(
        nearest
    )

    points = line.mark_point().encode(
        opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
    ).properties(
        title=f'Stat     x     INV'
    )

    text = line.mark_text(align='right', dx=-10, dy=-10).encode(
        text=alt.condition(nearest, f'Revenue:Q', alt.value(' '))
    ).transform_calculate(label='"INV: " + datum.Revenue')


    rules = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='black', size=0.70).encode(
        x=f'Stat:Q',
    ).transform_filter(
        nearest
    )

    chart = alt.layer(
        line, selectors, points, rules, text
    )

    return chart
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are calculating the label, but never actually using it in an encoding. Try this instead:

```
text = line.mark_text(align='right', dx=-10, dy=-10).encode(
        text=alt.condition(nearest, 'label:N', alt.value(' '))
    ).transform_calculate(label='"INV: " + datum.Revenue')
```

Comment: I keep seeing only the amount of the column "Revenue", without any text addition to it.

Comment: In fact, it seems the "transform_calculate" isn't changing anything.

Comment: The calculate transform as written does not change anything: it creates a new field named “label”, which your original code never references. If you want to use the calculated value in an encoding, you need to specify that explicitly, as in the snippet in my answer.

Comment: It worked when I am plotting a basic line or area chart. But if I do the same with multiple lines inside a for loop, then only the last label and its amount appears for all.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "do the same with multiple lines inside a for loop". Perhaps you can ask another question with more detail?